# Generators of Lie groups in physics

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

I asked this question in physics SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453742/dimension-of-lie-algebra-and-lie-group-generators). But I was not satisfied.

As we solving something related to symmetry transformations, we need Lie groups. Also Lie algebra is very important to generate those transformations.

E.g. the generators of $SO(3)$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&i&0\\-i&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&i\\0&0&0\\-i&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&i\\0&-i&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Why there is an i in the front.. The thing it is not so wrong if we just consider the Lie algebra as a vector space. But when we use the Lie bracket we will also get those real ones.. But the Lie algebra is three real dimensional.. Now, it is 6.

Comment: No, $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is a real $3$-dimensional vector space. Simply forget about the $i$ in front. The last matrix not skew-symmetric, as it should be.

Comment: I thought $SO(3)$ was the Lie group, not the Lie algebra, which I'd write as $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Also, I know physicists love their $i$s, but I don't.

Comment: that $i$ is just a part of a physics convention, coming from quantum mechanics. The correct math definition has no $i$'s, so just delete them.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So true.. I gave the link to where I asked in physics SE. They were still persisting on it... mathematically, it is simply wrong...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, in physics, they call the three matrices generators (or infinitesimal generators), just simply elements form the Lie algebra of a Lie group when we $\exp$ them we get the elements in the Lie group. For me it does not make sense... Because generators of a (Lie) group in algebra are a subset of the **group** and span the whole group... Last one was a typo.

Comment: Yes, in physics this convention is OK. I agree with the comments on physics SE (sorry), but in mathematics the convention for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is clearly without the factor $i$.

Answer (score 4):

Just a reminder of ***facts*** concerning physics usage.

Because quantum physics relies on *unitary* operators, the symmetry group elements are unitary matrices, so then exponentials of *iJ* where the *J*s are *Hermitean* operators, the standard convention for operators in physics. Commutators of such Hermitean *J*s are antihermitean, so *not* in the Lie algebra: in physics structure constants are normally pure imaginary, so they can multiply hermitean generators.

This is all there is to it, as @Dietrich Burde instructs you. The highly unconventional adjoint rep generators *J* you wrote down conform to this convention, but, of course, as you might be familiar, physics normally uses an equivalent representation for them, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins). Multiplying them by *i* and exponentiating yields a unitary group element in both cases but real orthogonal group elements only for your pure imaginary (Hermitean) basis. I gather you took the *real antisymmetric* generators of classical rotations and physics and multiplied them by i to make them Hermitean, assuming somehow physicsists use those, which they rarely would.